# Microsoft USD - Open different entities in a different tab

Tags: dynamics-crm, unified-service-desk

I have a Phonecall hosted control opened inside unified service desk as one of the tab and i have a few grids on that page.

On click of any grid inside my phone call page the respective entity is displayed on the same page.

Like for example if I click on customer product grid entity then that grid is opened similarly, there are other grids on which the user can click and it will load that entity on the same tab.

Now, the issue is as i said earlier that my new entity is being loaded on the same hosted control that is my phone call page. I want to prevent this from happening.

I want to display a different tab for whatever record is clicked within my PhoneCall Hosted control so this way my Phone Call Page is still there.

I know i can do this using Windows Navigation Rule but I will have to create different navigation rules for my different entities and then in future if any other grid is added in my phone call page then i will need to add another navigation rule to cater it. This is not the best approach, I want it to be dynamic. Is there any other way where I can open a different tab if a record is clicked from my phonecall page?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new windows navigation rule. The "From" field should be your Phone Call Page. Leave the Entity, From search, and URL fields in the "Route Logic" section blank. Windows Nav Rules get executed in order, and once they find a match it stops executing. So make the order low enough so that it gets executed where you want it to.

The "Target Tab" and "Show Tab" fields should be a new hosted control that you want the popup to open in. The action is "Route Window".

As far as route type, you are going to have to play with this a bit. I think opening stuff from a subgrid is Route Type "Popup", but you might need to create 2 very similar rules (one with route type "popup" and the other with route type "in place") to account for all scenarios.

See the example screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of Windows Nav Rule Example]